# Changing axis on Matplotlib to a specific range

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, axis

I have a code where I am plotting Galactic latitude against Galactic longitudes of planetary nebula, but the plot isn't easy to interrupt with the current axis.
For now the xaxis has the range 0 - 360, but I would like it to go from 180 to 0 and then 360 to 180.
so you can clearly see the distributions of PN at the Galactic center and the anti-center.

I've included a plot of what I mean here.
[image]
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
pylab.xlim(rangestart, rangeend)
pylab.ylim(rangestart, rangeend)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this isn't what I was asking for.

Comment: @Sarah sorry, it would help to see your code. Can you upload it to pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out how to do this.

```
from astropy.io import ascii
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
tbl = ascii.read("SC1313_ob0h2eugqt-bipolartest.csv")
data = pd.read_csv("SC1313_ob0h2eugqt-bipolartest.csv")
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
i = 0;
while i < 546:
if data['Glon1'].iloc[i] > 180:
data['Glon1'].iloc[i] = -360 + data['Glon1'].iloc[i]
i = i + 1;
   print(i)
else:        
    i = i + 1;
    print(i)
ax.plot(data['Glon1'],data['Glat'],'.', color = 'teal')
plt.yticks(np.arange(-90, 100, 10.0))
plt.grid()
```